# Як правильно перекласти з англійської Coordinate System Handedness?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Я перекладаю статтю про рейтрейсинг трикутників для того щоб потім це використовувати для полігональних моделей.

В [статті](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/ray-tracing-rendering-a-triangle/geometry-of-a-triangle) є підзаголовок - Coordinate System Handedness

Я розумію, що це пов'язано з правобічною і лівобічною системою координат.
Але як це точно перекласти?

Розділ, який я перекладаю пов'язаний з визначенням нормалі поверхні трикутника. Тому в залежності від того, яку систему координат я буду використовувати чи лівобічну, чи правобічну, нормаль (тобто векторний добуток від двох векторів) буде направлена в ту чи іншу сторону трикутника. Нормаль - це перпендикулярний вектор до поверхні площини.

Comment: Ваші попередні запитання містили більш-менш пояснення терміну своїми словами. Можете, будь ласка, зробити це і до наведеного терміну? Далеко не усі з нас знайомі із 3D рендерингом. Окремо від цього, в інших галузях науки (хімії) використовується збиральний термін **хіральність** (напр., для праворуких і ліворуких молекул).

Comment: +1 до хіральності

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Беручи до уваги ваші пояснення, йде мова про напрямленість або орієнтацію системи координат. Адже кожна система координат у тривимірному просторі визначається своїм ортонормованим базисом, який є УПОРЯДКОВАНОЮ трійкою одиничних векторів (великі букви - мої). Якраз цей порядок векторів визначає два можливі набори - ліва та права трійка векторів.

Мені, як математику, слово хіральність зовсім не до вподоби. Ніколи на нього не надибував у математичних текстах.

А позаяк кожний вектор з базису визначає координатну вісь, то здається у даній ситуації пасує такий переклад „Напрямленість системи координат“, Орієнтація системи координат“ або „Порядок осей системи координат“.
Вибирайте, який влучніший.

Comment: +1, та це все не те, що запитували. Потрібен варіант перекладу, який би вказував саме на *right*- або *left*-handedness

Comment: Якраз саме про це й запитували. Нагадаю формулювання питання - Як правильно перекласти з англійської Coordinate System Handedness? У моїй відповіді якраз і є пояснення звідки там береться ліва та права система координат. Питалися саме про той підзаголовок.

Comment: Так, я мав на увазі переклад самого заголовку. І у вас він вийшов дуже влучний, простий та зрозумілий.

Comment: Так, я помилився, чогось сконцентрувався саме на право-/ліво-.

Answer (score 4):

Раджу консультуватись із e2u. [Ось](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=handedness&dicts=all&highlight=on) результат пошуку звідти:

> **handedness** хіра́льність див. *тж chirality*
>       ['hændɪdnəs]
>   **left-handedness** лівооберто́вість; закру́ченість улі́во
>       [ˌlεft'hændɪdnəs]
>   **right-handedness** правооберто́вість; закру́ченість упра́во
>       [ˌraɪt'hændɪdnəs]

Хоча перше, що мені спало на думку -- ліво-, праворучність, але таких слів немає:)